# How to loop through all files (recursively) in a certain directory

Tags: bash, loops, recursion

My task is to loop through all files (recursively) in a certain directory. The directory path is specified in the first parameter of the program.
Now I have the following one-liner:

```
find * -type f -exec echo "put {}" \;
```

, but I don't know how to specify directory path as the first parameter and how left * if there are no parameters.

If I'm doing it like:

```
$YOUR_DIR = "*";
find "$YOUR_DIR" -type f -exec echo "put {}" \;
```

it isn't working.

Please, help me.

Comment: Thats not how you use find. Assuming your directory is /usr, you'd run: find /usr -type f -exec echo ... etc. The 1st parameter to find is the directory you wish to find _from_. If you want to specify filenames, you'd use -name "<name spec>" as well: i.e. find /usr -name "ls*"

Comment: Your command would assume that your directory is named `*`. While legal, this would be a quite unusual name for a directory. What did you want to express here?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters to a script are identified numerically as `${1}`, `${2}`, etc. (or `$1`, `$2`, etc.). You can also refer to ALL parameters using `${*}` (or `$*`).  But you are using `*`, without the preceding dollar sign. This has a completely different meaning. It means 'all entries in the current directory'.

You should really just be using one directory, so check the first parameter, and make sure it is a directory before using it:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d "${1}" ]; then
  echo "'${1}' is not a directory."
  exit 1
fi

find "${1}" -type f -exec echo "put {}" \;
```